# Copy select option values from one form to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){

  var form1 = $('#form1'), 
      form2 = $('#form2');  

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(':select[name]', form2).val(function(){
      return $(':input[name='+ this.name +']', form1).val();
    });
  });

});
</script>
```

and I have these two HTML forms

```
<form id="form1">
    <select id="a" name="a" size="5" style="width: 400px;">
        <option value="01">001</option>
        <option value="02">002</option>
        <option value="03">003</option>
        <option value="04">004</option>
     </select>
 </form>
 <form id="form2">
       <input name="a" type=text>
 </form>
```

I'd like that when the user selects an option from a list it immediately updates the input box in form2. It works in between two input boxes but not with a select - http://jsbin.com/jalomeyu/4/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Off topic: You have nested document.ready functions in your code above. See http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply listen to the `change` event on the select element. Also, there are some issues with your original code:

- `:select` is not a valid pseudo-class. Just use `select[name]`.
- You are nesting `$(document).ready(function() {...}` in another one. `$(function() {...}` is a shorthand ;)

Here is the corrected JS:

```
$(function(){

  var form1 = $('#form1'), 
      form2 = $('#form2');  

  $('select[name]', form1).change(function(){
    $(':input', form2).val(this.value);
  });

});
```

See updated JSbin here: http://jsbin.com/tajijajife/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code below,

HTML,

```
<form id="form1">
    <select id="a" name="a" style="width: 185px;">
        <option value="Ali">Ali</option>
        <option value="Ahmad">Ahmad</option>
        <option value="Osama">Osama</option>
        <option value="Zain">Zain</option>
        <option value="Ahad">Ahad</option>
        <option value="Bakar">Bakar</option>
        <option value="Arish">Arish</option>
        <option value="Anjum">Anjum</option>
     </select>

 </form>
 <form id="form2">
       <input name="a" type=text>
 </form>
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){

  var form1 = $('#form1'), 
      form2 = $('#form2');  

  $('#form1').change(function(){
    $(':input[name]', form2).val(function(){
      return $(':input[name='+ this.name +']', form1).val();
    });
  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do the update when the first select element changes. For example:

```
$(function() {
    var form1 = $('#form1'), 
        form2 = $('#form2');

     $(form1).change(function() {
         $(':select[name]', form2).val(function() {
             return $(':input[name='+ this.name +']', form1).val();
         });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `keyup` function to run every time a key is pressed.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form1 = $('#form1'),
    form2 = $('#form2');

  $('input').keyup(function() {
    $(':input[name]', form2).val(function() {
      return $(':input[name=' + this.name + ']', form1).val();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Testing</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1">
    <input name="a" type=text value="test">
    <input name="b" type=text>
    <input name="c" type=text>
    <input name="d" type=text>
  </form>
  <form id="form2">
    <input name="a" type=text>
    <input name="b" type=text>
    <input name="c" type=text>
    <input name="d" type=text>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```